# Convert the Grammar to Chomsky normal form

Tags: computer-science

S --> A | ABa | AbA

A --> Aa | lambda

B --> Bb | BC

C --> CB | CA | bB

I need help changing this grammar to chomsky normal, This is the answer i came up with, but i brought it to my professor and he advised me it was wrong. He refused to tell me how to fix it because it is has to be turned in for a grade later. All help is appreciated.

GL: S→ ZA | AW A→ AA | a B→ AX | YY Z→ a Y→ b X→ YB W→ BZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge maybe rusty, but I'll try to help.

According to wikipedia,

> In formal language theory, a context-free grammar is said to be in Chomsky normal form if all of its production rules are of the form:
>
> - A -> BC, or
> - A -> α, or
> - S -> ε
>
> where A, B, C are nonterminal symbols, α is a terminal symbol, S is the start symbol, and ε is the empty string. Also, neither B nor C may be the start symbol.

I am considering your lambda is epsilon `ε`. Let's rephrase your grammar to

```
S -> A
S -> ABa
S -> AbA
A -> Aa
A -> ε
B -> Bb
B -> BC
C -> CB
C -> CA
C -> bB
```

Then, add a new variable `S0` as the new start variable, so it becomes

```
S0 -> S
S  -> A
S  -> ABa
S  -> AbA
A  -> Aa
A  -> ε
B  -> Bb
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> bB
```

Next, remove the `ε` rules, so it becomes

```
S0 -> S
S  -> A
S  -> ABa
S  -> AbA
A  -> Aa
B  -> Bb
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> bB
```

Introduce new variable `Y->a` and `Z->b`.

```
S0 -> S
S  -> A
S  -> ABa
S  -> AbA
A  -> Aa
B  -> Bb
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> bB
Y  -> a
Z  -> b
```

Rewrite the RHS rules:

```
S0 -> S
S  -> A
S  -> ABY
S  -> AZA
A  -> AY
B  -> BZ
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> ZB
Y  -> a
Z  -> b
```

Introduce new variable `D->AB` and `E->AZ`, so it becomes

```
S0 -> S
S  -> A
S  -> DY
S  -> EA
A  -> AY
B  -> BZ
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> ZB
D  -> AB
E  -> AZ
Y  -> a
Z  -> b
```

For `S->A`, duplicate the one rule where `S` occurs on RHS and inline the rule:

```
S0 -> S
S0 -> A
S  -> DY
S  -> EA
A  -> AY
B  -> BZ
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> ZB
D  -> AB
E  -> AZ
Y  -> a
Z  -> b
```

Combine the rule for `S0` and `S`.

```
S0 -> DY
S0 -> EA
S0 -> AY
A  -> AY
B  -> BZ
B  -> BC
C  -> CB
C  -> CA
C  -> ZB
D  -> AB
E  -> AZ
Y  -> a
Z  -> b
```

Now we have the grammar in chomsky normal form.